# Regular expression transformation for wiki-like mark-up

Tags: html, regex, xhtml, wiki, user-input

Consider the following mark-up input:

```
* Line 1
* Line 2
:* Line 2.1
:* Line 2.2
* Line 3
```

This is typically coded as:

```
  <ul>
    <li>Line 1</li>
    <li>Line 2</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Line 2.1</li>
      <li>Line 2.2</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Line 3</li>
  </ul>
```

My questions:

- What would be a good representation for the same input using a single line?
- What is the regular expression to generate the corresponding XHTML?

For example, the single line input format could be:

```
> Line 1 > Line 2 >> Line 2.1 >> Line 2.2 > Line 3
```

With `>` being unordered list item delimiter. I chose `>` because the text might include typical punctuation marks. Using » (or other such non-104-key keys) would be fun, but not as easy to type.

The line input format could also be:

```
[Line 1][Line 2 [Line 2.1][Line 2.2]][Line 3]
```

**Update #1** - The problem is a little simpler. The number of nests can be limited to three. A general solution for n-levels deep would still be cool.

**Update #2** - XHTML, not HTML.

**Update #3** - Another possible input format.

**Update #4** - Java solutions (or pure regex) are most welcome.

**Update #5**

Revised code:

```
String in = " * Line 1 * Line 2 > * Line 2.1 * Line 2.2 < * Line 3";

String sub = "<ul>" + in.replace( " > ", "<ul>" ) + "</ul>";

sub = sub.replace( " < ", "</ul>" );

sub = sub.replaceAll( "( | >)\\* ([^*<>]*)", "<li>$2</li>" );

System.out.println( "Result: " + sub );
```

Prints the following:

```
Result: <ul><li>Line 1 </li>* Line 2<ul>* Line 2.1<li>Line 2.2</li></ul>* Line 3
```

Comment: So, should I ignore everything above "My questions" in my answer?  It seems like unneeded information as you don't reference it in your question.

Comment: "What would be a good representation for the same input using a single line?" -- That question refers to the mark-up input given at the top of the question. It might not be necessary, but I'd rather be slightly redundant than leave room for ambiguity.

Comment: Nesting brackets, IMHO, will only appeal to common users with a LISP background... but I did fix my answer to give what I think will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

A working solution follows:

```
public class Test {
  public Test() {
  }

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    String in = "= Line 1 = Line 2 > = Line 2.1 = Line 2.2 < = Line 3";

    in = in.replaceAll( "= ([^=<>]*)", "<li>$1</li>" );
    in = in.replace( ">> ", "><ul>" );
    in = in.replace( ">< ", "></ul>" );
    in = "<ul>" + in + "</ul>";
    System.out.println( in );
  }
}
```

This creates the desired XHTML fragment:

```
<ul><li>Line 1 </li><li>Line 2 </li><ul><li>Line 2.1 </li><li>Line 2.2 </li></ul><li>Line 3</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your example seems fine to me.

```
 > Line 1 > Line 2 >> Line 2.1 >> Line 2.2 > Line 3
```

Unfortunately, pure RegEx can't keep track of which nesting level you are on, so it won't know where to put the **/UL** close tags.

Something like this might work:

```
 * Line 1 * Line 2 > * Line 2.1 * Line 2.2 < * Line 3
```

Here, the greater-than and less-than move up and down the hierarchy, and the asterisks are the delimiters for the bullets. The spaces before and after each are used as a sort of escape sequence, so you can still use those characters literally or for other purposes like italics and bold when they aren't surrounded by spaces.

A stab at the RegEx:

```
 string ol = "<ul>" & RegEx.Replace(t, " > ", "<ul>") & "</ul>";
 ol = RegEx.Replace(ol, " < ", "</ul>");
 ol = RegEx.Replace(ol, "( |>)\\* ([^*<>]*)", "<li>\\2</li>");
```

**Edit:** Adjusted to produce XHTML, closing the LI tags, based on comment below. Also fixed my C# syntax.

**Final edit:** I think the \ * and \ 2 in the last Replace need to be escaped for C#, fixing. Also, note that the first two Replace() calls can use String.Replace() rather than RegEx, which will likely be faster.

Comment: if you replace "-([^-<>]*)" with "<li>\1</li>" you will get valid xhtml

Comment: cobbal, yes, but that pattern would replace all hyphens, not just the ones intended to be bullets. Using a hyphen was probably a bad choice since it is common in English anyway--an asterisk would be just as intuitive and would work better for your enhancement.

Comment: cobbal, I adjusted my code to use asterisks, made a tweak to your suggestion so it would work in the code above (needed space-or-greater-than because of the replacements above that potentially strip the space before the LI character).

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using regular expressions as a parsing and transformation tool. Regular expressions tend to have high overhead, and are not the most efficient means of parsing a language...which is what you are really asking it to do. You have created a language, simple as it is, and you should treat it as such. I recommend writing an actual, dedicated parser for your WIKI-style formatting code. Since you can target the parser specifically to your language, it should be more efficient. In addition, you won't have to create some frightening monstrosity that is a regex to parse your language and handle all of its nuances. In the long run, you gain the benefits of clearer code, better maintainability, etc.

I suggest the following resources:

- [ANTLR](http://www.antlr2.org/)
- [Compilers: Principals, Techniques, Tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201100886)
- [Parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)

Comment: I see. Regex is a possibility, however, I am not sure if will actually meet your needs. Antler might still be helpful. It is a parser generator, and you're grammar seems fairly simple. Even though its a one-off, you might still be able to use ANTLER to generate a parser, and write a simple C# program to perform the conversion, in less time than it takes to figure out the RegEx. ;)

Comment: ANTLR is available for Java too, but if you were able to create a RegEx version in 6 minutes, then I would agree, ANTLR is out. :P